# C++ statically assert that only certain enum values are present

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a enum with that looks like this:

```
enum class States{
     STATE_A,
     STATE_B,
     STATE_C,
     STATE_D,
     STATE_E
}
```

And I have a guard somewhere where I am checking:

```
if( state == STATE_A || state = STATE_C || state == STATE_D || state == STATE_E)
```

so excluding `STATE_B`. I have done this deliberately so that the inclusion of another state does not change existing behaviour. The question here would be if I can have both, meaning the convenience of writing `state != STATE_B` and compile time robustness against changes to the `States` enum.

I would think that this can be done with a `static_assert` somehow but how would I go about that?
The States do not have any assigned value nor particular ordering.

Comment: `state` is a runtime variable, so I don't think there are ways that a compiler can decide at compile time. Or you can use `constexpr` and `if constexpr` for constant variables.

Comment: Yeah I was more thinking of if there is a way to assert "enum States only contains these variants"

Comment: Can excluded `STATE_B` be removed from the enum class?  Can you have a separate `enum class States_sans_B { A, C, D, E };`?

Comment: whats wrong with `state != STATE_B` ?

Comment: You would need some sort of reflection feature on the enum type, which C++ does not have. Some way of replacing the enum with something providing its own reflection (likely using preprocessor macros) could make this possible, at the cost of making the changed enum definition harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like the concept of subtypes with a static predicate introduced in Ada 2012. An example similar to your question is

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type states is (A, B, C, D, E);
   subtype valid_states is states with
        Static_Predicate => valid_states in A | C | D | E;
begin
   --  Insert code here.
   null;
end Main;
```

The type states above is an enumeration including values A through E. The subtype valid_states is a subset of states excluding B. Every instance of valid_states is also an instance of states, but no instance of valid_states may contain the value B.

I believe you will need to define a States class and then derive a subclass from that excluding B.